# Create IP and Port Scanner Python

Tags: python

I am having trouble creating an port scanner that scans IP addresses and ports at the same time. The port scanning part of the code works fine but I cannot add the IP addresses in correctly and make the loops work in sync. I am asking the user to input the first 3 octets, then the code will use the fourth octet to scan and move the number forward. The output is supposed to look like:

IP 127.0.0.1 Port 22 is closed
IP 127.0.0.1 Port 23 is closed
IP 127.0.0.1 Port 24 is closed
IP 127.0.0.2 Port 22 is closed
IP 127.0.0.2 Port 23 is closed
IP 127.0.0.2 Port 24 is closed
....etc

Here is the code so far:

```
    import socket

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    server = 'google.com'

    portstart = int(input("Enter starting port number to scan: "))
    portend = int(input("Enter end port number to scan: "))
    octets = input("Enter the first 3 octets of an IP to scan:")
    fourthoctet = 1

    for portnum in range (portstart, portend):
        try:
        s.connect((server,portnum))
           print("port",portnum,"is open")
        except:
           print("port",portnum,"is closed")
        for fourthoctet in range (1,256):
           print("IP", octets,".",fourthoctet)
```

Comment: wouldn't your ports print first then basically "IP `octets`.(1-255)"

Comment: Yes, they print out that way with the way i have the code now. The directions for this assignment are as follows:  Start by prompting the user to enter the first 3 octets of an IP address.  For example:  127.0.0   Then, build an outer loop that will allow scanning for multiple IP addresses.  We will always be scanning 255 different IP addresses.
We will scan all IPs starting with inputted first 3 octets, for example:
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.2
127.0.0.3
127.0.0.254
In other words we will scan for all 254 fourth octet possibilities

Comment: then isn't the problem really just you having your port and fourthoctet loop in the wrong order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by your desired output, shouldn't your loop look like this instead?

```
for fourthoctet in range (1,256):
  for portnum in range (portstart, portend):
    print("IP", octets,".",fourthoctet, end=" ")
    try:
      s.connect((server,portnum))
      print("port",portnum,"is open")
    except:
      print("port",portnum,"is closed")
```

Comment: Yes,thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for. I am new to python so even the simple answers seem difficult to find.

Comment: @JamesPi Well it's not exactly python specific syntax, but general logic. Basically the inner for loops run first (to completion) before the outer ones, just remember that. Same goes for every other programming language